# Flutter Firebase, logout other user than me

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

In my Flutter management application, I would like to disconnect a user other than the one I am logged in with.

I use Firebase as my database, and use email and a password to log in. I don't use a token

I know that in order to disconnect the user I am currently logged in with, it has to be done like this:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
```

I can't figure out how to disconnect another user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Firebase client-side SDKs, you can only sign out the currently signed in user. There is no way to sign out a user on another device.

If you want to add user management functionality to your client-side application, you'll want to use a combination of the client-side SDK and a server-side Admin SDK to build this functionality:

1. Use the Admin SDK in a trusted environment (such as a server you control, or Cloud Functions) to implement the user management functionality.
2. Create an endpoint that clients can call that exposes this functionality, for example as a [callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).
3. In that endpoint be sure to check whether the user is authorized, for example by [checking their ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) to see if it has a certain UID or custom claim.
4. Call the custom endpoint from your client-side code.